# Как текущий вид на сцену , сделать видом для камеры. Unity 3d

Tags: unity3d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Например текущий вид сделать видом для камеры на сцене.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Выберите камеру в окне hierarchy
2. Нажмите ctrl + shift + f    Или падающее меню GameObject -> Align with view

Comment: Спасибо Aleksandr Akimov

Comment: Пожалуйста. На стек оверфлов автор вопроса, если ответом удовлетворен, отмечает галочкой, как лучший. Для остальных это сигнал, что ответ получен.